# Hiding and showing different scrollviews

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

So I have two scroll views that I want my XIB to show.

My first scroll view is loaded with the XIB and I want the second to be loaded when a button is pressed.
Does any body know how I can do this?

Comment: why not make the second hidden, then on the button press you can show it ?

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView inherits from UIView. All you have to do is set it's hidden property to hidden. It is a simple set method. By default it will display as long as you add the view.

On your click action or method triggered simply set the property for the UIScrollView like:

```
[myScrollView setHidden:NO];
```

And if you want it to disappear again, on a different action:

```
[myScrollView setHidden:YES];
```